# Automatic (telephone) links on numbers for mobile firefox

Tags: firefox, mobile, hyperlink, numbers

I noticed that Firefox on iPhone (ios) adds an automatic link on numbers with at least 7 digits (even if the digits are interspersed with spaces) interpreting these numbers as telephone numbers.

The directive that prevents this automatism  works for Safari but not for Firefox.

Is there a solution to prevent Firefox on mobile from not automatically adding links to numbers?

Thank you
Vincenzo

Comment: I tried a non-breaking space, but no joy. I fixed it the non-aesthetic way by sticking in an unneeded colon between the data. It's unwanted and noisy, but it worked.